# How can you loop through lines of text and join if the lines are shorter than 50 characters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I am trying to loop through each line of text in a document and if the line is shorter than 50 characters, then join them together.

What I am having trouble figuring out is the hierarchy of the loop.  What I have right now is:

```
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f1:
    with open(sys.argv[2], 'a') as f2:
        lines = f1.readlines()
        for index, line in enumerate(lines):
            if len(line) > 50:
                f2.write(line)
            else:
                # Something that would take the next line and join to the current index
                line1 = line
```

I need to keep the current line and then loop again for the next line to join.  Could I use a while loop and add the line from the next index?

Comment: I need to point out that you can do this on Linux and MacOIS without any programming at all by doing `fmt -w50 infile > outfile`.

Comment: wouldn't that be a maximum of 50 characters? The goal seems to be to have a minimum of 50

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would concatenate lines until it sees a line with more than 50 characters.

```py
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f1:
    with open(sys.argv[2], 'a') as f2:
        lines = f1.readlines()
        prev_line = ""
        for index, line in enumerate(lines):
            if len(line) > 50:
                f2.write(prev_line + line)
                prev_line = ""
            else:
                prev_line += line
```

If you need to write once the concatenated line reaches 50 characters:

```py
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f1:
    with open(sys.argv[2], 'a') as f2:
        lines = f1.readlines()
        prev_line = ""
        for index, line in enumerate(lines):
            line += prev_line
            if len(line) > 50:
                f2.write(line)
                prev_line = ""
            else:
                prev_line += line
```

Comment: Thank you for your help @gshpychka.  One follow up question.  So, if I need to remove the paragraph, I can use the .strip() to remove the (\n) so they will all be on the same line.  However, when I introduce this by updating the line `line.strip() =+ prev_line` I am getting an error `SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call`.

Comment: `line.strip()` modifies the string in-place and doesn't return anything. Use `line.strip()` after concatenating it to `prev_line`.

Comment: I see, so save it as a variable then use the `.strip()`?
`x = line += prev_line`
`x.strip()`

Comment: `+=` also doesn't return anything. You can use `x = line + prev_line` instead, and strip that.